# Logitech H600 mic not working, Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: microphone, logitech, headset

I just got the H600. The audio output works fine, however I can't get the mic to work. When I check the sound settings, "Microphone H600[Wireless Headset]" is listed as the source. The input level shows no activity. I've tried muting/unmuting with the button on the mic. (Which beep indicates mute is on, the rising beep or falling beep?)

Also, when in Audacity which input source should I pick? There are so many choices. None seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution posted [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/3h78b0/logitech_h600_mic_not_working_ubuntu_1504/). Worked for me.

> Open terminal and enter `sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`,
>   hit Enter. It will open a file `alsa-base.conf`. scroll to the end of
>   the file and add this
>
> ```
> options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1"
> ```
>
> as a
>   new line, save the file and reboot. Enjoy this!

More details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting